# Prevent auto sign in with Google plus

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am trying to implement Google+ sign in for web sites.

My desired flow is:

1. User lands on login page
2. Clicks Google Sign In button
3. I receive email and processing it on server side

The problem is, whatever script I try, Google always invoking and UNWANTED auto sign in. I want it to be initiated only when user clicks the button and prevent auto triggering google events.

Comment: "I receive email and processing it on server side" what does this mean? And what does 'auto sign in' mean? What do you mean by 'auto'?

Comment: There is a code sample provided by google+ platform, how to retrieve email of user. I send this email to MY server in order to create user account. By auto - I mean when user lands on page where google+ sign in button located - google script attempts to sign in this user automatically without him pressing the button

Comment: Which code sample are you using? Can you post the link here?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'auto sign in' thing you mention is how the Google+ Sign In method functions by default. If you want full control of the sign in process, you need to use the [Google Plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) and manually go through the whole OAuth process. I don't know what platform you're developing on but there are plenty of [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/) for the Google+ API.

If you insist on using the Google+ JavaScript library, here's one option:  The Google Plus Sign In button has a [`data-callback`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#button_attr_callback) attribute. An [`object`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/session-state) is passed into this callback function. That object has a `status` property which you can use to check whether the sign-in was made 'automatically' as you mention, or was made after the user clicked the sign-in button.

```
function google_plus_signin_callback(authResult){
    if(authResult.status.method == 'AUTO'){
        // handle auto sign-in scenario
    }else if(authResult.status.method == 'PROMPT') {
        // handle user initiated sign-in scenario
    }
}
```

So if the user was signed in automatically, you can use the [`sign out`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/sign-out) method to sign her out or you can try doing something else depending on how you want your application to behave.